# Prisma ORM Generated SQL Performance

Tags: prisma

I have a query that I've written in Prisma. It basically connects 7 tables, each of which only has maybe 2-4 rows. Yes, 2-4 rows, that's it.

The query that Prisma generates can take upwards of 2-3 minutes to run.

When I write the query directly in SQL, it runs in 1ms.

So, the query I write looks like :

```
SELECT *
    FROM rubricCellAssessment
    INNER JOIN rubricAssessment ON rubricCellAssessment.rubricAssessmentId = rubricAssessment.id
    INNER JOIN rubricCell ON rubricCellAssessment.rubricCellId = rubricCell.id
    INNER JOIN criteriaDescriptor ON rubricCell.criteriaDescriptorId = criteriaDescriptor.id
    INNER JOIN criteria ON criteriaDescriptor.criteriaId = criteria.id
    INNER JOIN skill ON criteria.skillId = skill.id
    INNER JOIN user AS student ON rubricAssessment.studentId = student.id
    INNER JOIN user AS assessor ON rubricAssessment.assessorId = assessor.id
    LEFT JOIN studentContentBase ON rubricAssessment.studentContentBaseId = studentContentBase.id
    WHERE student.userTypeId = 1
      AND assessor.userTypeId IN (2, 1000, 3)
      AND skill.id = 'bd47bfff-760c-4fec-86d2-1063bbd89d63'
      AND criteriaDescriptor.criteriaId = criteria.id
      AND rubricCell.criteriaDescriptorId = criteriaDescriptor.id;
```

The query prisma produces looks like this:

```
select
    `lp-mvp`.`RubricCellAssessment`.`id`,
    `lp-mvp`.`RubricCellAssessment`.`createdAt`,
    `lp-mvp`.`RubricCellAssessment`.`updatedAt`,
    `lp-mvp`.`RubricCellAssessment`.`assessmentValue`,
    `lp-mvp`.`RubricCellAssessment`.`rubricCellId`,
    `lp-mvp`.`RubricCellAssessment`.`rubricAssessmentId`
from
    `lp-mvp`.`RubricCellAssessment`
where
    ((`lp-mvp`.`RubricCellAssessment`.`id`) in (
    select
        `t0`.`id`
    from
        `lp-mvp`.`RubricCellAssessment` as `t0`
    inner join `lp-mvp`.`RubricAssessment` as `j0` on
        (`j0`.`id`) = (`t0`.`rubricAssessmentId`)
    where
        ((`j0`.`id`) in (
        select
            `t1`.`id`
        from
            `lp-mvp`.`RubricAssessment` as `t1`
        inner join `lp-mvp`.`User` as `j1` on
            (`j1`.`id`) = (`t1`.`studentId`)
        where
            (`j1`.`userTypeId` = 1
                and `t1`.`id` is not null))
        and `t0`.`id` is not null))
    and (`lp-mvp`.`RubricCellAssessment`.`id`) in (
    select
        `t0`.`id`
    from
        `lp-mvp`.`RubricCellAssessment` as `t0`
    inner join `lp-mvp`.`RubricCell` as `j0` on
        (`j0`.`id`) = (`t0`.`rubricCellId`)
    where
        ((`j0`.`id`) in (
        select
            `t1`.`id`
        from
            `lp-mvp`.`RubricCell` as `t1`
        inner join `lp-mvp`.`CriteriaDescriptor` as `j1` on
            (`j1`.`id`) = (`t1`.`criteriaDescriptorId`)
        where
            ((`j1`.`id`) in (
            select
                `t2`.`id`
            from
                `lp-mvp`.`CriteriaDescriptor` as `t2`
            inner join `lp-mvp`.`Criteria` as `j2` on
                (`j2`.`id`) = (`t2`.`criteriaId`)
            where
                ((`j2`.`id`) in (
                select
                    `t3`.`id`
                from
                    `lp-mvp`.`Criteria` as `t3`
                inner join `lp-mvp`.`Skill` as `j3` on
                    (`j3`.`id`) = (`t3`.`skillId`)
                where
                    (`j3`.`id` = "bd47bfff-760c-4fec-86d2-1063bbd89d63"
                        and `t3`.`id` is not null))
                and `t2`.`id` is not null))
            and `t1`.`id` is not null))
        and `t0`.`id` is not null))
    and (`lp-mvp`.`RubricCellAssessment`.`id`) in (
    select
        `t0`.`id`
    from
        `lp-mvp`.`RubricCellAssessment` as `t0`
    inner join `lp-mvp`.`RubricAssessment` as `j0` on
        (`j0`.`id`) = (`t0`.`rubricAssessmentId`)
    where
        ((`j0`.`id`) in (
        select
            `t1`.`id`
        from
            `lp-mvp`.`RubricAssessment` as `t1`
        inner join `lp-mvp`.`User` as `j1` on
            (`j1`.`id`) = (`t1`.`assessorId`)
        where
            (`j1`.`userTypeId` in (2,1000,3)
                and `t1`.`id` is not null))
        and `t0`.`id` is not null))
    and (`lp-mvp`.`RubricCellAssessment`.`id`) in (
    select
        `t0`.`id`
    from
        `lp-mvp`.`RubricCellAssessment` as `t0`
    inner join `lp-mvp`.`RubricCell` as `j0` on
        (`j0`.`id`) = (`t0`.`rubricCellId`)
    where
        ((`j0`.`id`) in (
        select
            `t1`.`id`
        from
            `lp-mvp`.`RubricCell` as `t1`
        inner join `lp-mvp`.`CriteriaDescriptor` as `j1` on
            (`j1`.`id`) = (`t1`.`criteriaDescriptorId`)
        where
            ((`j1`.`id`) in (
            select
                `t2`.`id`
            from
                `lp-mvp`.`CriteriaDescriptor` as `t2`
            inner join `lp-mvp`.`Criteria` as `j2` on
                (`j2`.`id`) = (`t2`.`criteriaId`)
            where
                ((`j2`.`id`) in (
                select
                    `t3`.`id`
                from
                    `lp-mvp`.`Criteria` as `t3`
                inner join `lp-mvp`.`Skill` as `j3` on
                    (`j3`.`id`) = (`t3`.`skillId`)
                where
                    (`j3`.`id` = "bd47bfff-760c-4fec-86d2-1063bbd89d63"
                        and `t3`.`id` is not null))
                and `t2`.`id` is not null))
            and `t1`.`id` is not null))
        and `t0`.`id` is not null)))
```

Is there any way to optimize this (other than use RAWsql?)? I'm surprised Prisma's code generation is *this* bad, but I'd rather not move away from it at this point if possible.

All help gratefully accepted.